# How to re codesign iPhone app binary?

Tags: iphone, certificate, app-store-connect, codesign

I'd like to send a binary to a client without the source code.
How can here sign the app for distribution on it's own name without
recompiling everything (since he does not have the source code)
I'm not talking about adhoc distribution.
I've tried to codesign -f with another distribution profile but itunes
connect refuses it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client needs to send you his distribution certificate and personnal certificate with his public key, matching his iPhone developer identity, so you can compile the app with his informations.

Comment: That's complex for a client who does not even know what a certificate is. Seems there's a also a possibility for a client to add me as a user in their itunes connect account. It does not feel reality simpler though.

Comment: That's true. He can add you as a developer, but you will need his credidentials for some tasks (ie accessing iTunes connect), as some of them require administrator access level. But you should be able to get the correct certificates to compile the app with a deveoper account. : )